# Can the properties of a model be accessed indirectly in a Razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Can the properties of a model be accessed indirectly in a Razor view?

So instead of:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ColA)
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ColB)
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ColC)
```

Is something like the following possible?

```
@foreach (var col in Model.Columns)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model[col])
}
```

I should qualify that the model to be used will be an EF model:

```
public class Record
{
    [Key, Display(Name="Column A")]
    public string ColA { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Column B")]
    public string ColB { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Column C")]
    public string ColC { get; set; }
}

public class RecordDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Record> Records { get; set; }
}
```

How might I implement 'Columns' to show the display name for the property?

Answer (score 0):

If `Model.Columns` is a list that would almost work. You would need to change it to this though:

```
@foreach (var col in Model.Columns)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => col)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your view model is not adapted to the requirements of your view (which is to loop through some values and display labels about them). You could use a collection in your view model instead of properties as it will allow you to loop:

```
public IEnumerable<SomeModel> Columns { get; set; }
```

Then in your view instead of writing a loop you could use a display template:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Columns)
```

and then define the corresponding template which will automatically be rendered for each element of the Columns collection (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/SomeModel.cshtml`):

```
@model SomeModel
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.SomeModelProperty)
```